# Problems with FTP VB.net Downloading

Tags: vb.net, exception

OK so I am a VB.net Newb and I was wondering how I could do this: All I have to do, Is login to an ftp server virtually, then find an html file in a user specified directory, then open that user specified html file in the program. Here is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("ftp://user:pass@host/dir/" + TextBox2.Text + "/" + TextBox1.Text + ".html")
    End Sub 
End Class
```

All that does is take the data from TextBox1-3, puts it into the string at different points, then searches. it. I am not sure if I am adding the values to the string right, but it comes up with no errors. But when I run it, put the info in the textboxes, then hit the button it generates an exception: ( Also I obvoisuly have my info for the user, and pass):

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Navigate2(Object& URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
       at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigate2(Object& URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
       at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(String urlString)
       at AIFS_Browser_v1.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\mikebenjcomcast.net\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AIFS Browser v1\AIFS Browser v1\Form1.vb:line 5
  InnerException:
```

And:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

This project is important to me. Will someone please help. I looked on line and didn't find anything I though I could use because lots of other people have had this exception but none of then were doing what I was. Please help! Also please explain any answers because I dont exactly know VB.net that well.

Comment: What are the values of `TextBox2.Text` and `TextBox1.Text` when the button is clicked? Does the combined string form a valid URL?

Comment: Yes it does. I make sure it does because whenever I type into the TB's, I use the code to see what stuff goes in what TB